# button value in javascript shows undefined

Tags: javascript, button, getelementsbytagname

```
[pure javascript code without the html body]
<script language="Javascript">
    [ creating buttons with the alphabets on it and its values the same]

  for(var a=1;a<=26;a++)
  {
  document.write("<input type='button' size='1' value="+String.fromCharCode(a +64)+" id='btn"+a+"' onclick='see()' >");
  }


document.write("<input type='text' size='10' id='box1' style='background-color:red'>")               

[normal textbox which should contain the data]
    function see()
      {
      [trying to put the value of button on textbox on buttonclick but gives me  undefined]


       var text;
       text=*document.getElementsByTagName*("button").value;
       document.getElementById("box1").value=text;
      }

</script>
```

i have tried document.getElementsByTagName or even by Id gives undefined where as i want the value of the button to on textbox..
i have used forloop as i had to create about 26 buttons

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array so `.value` won't work as you have it. you need to loop through the array that is text and do text[index].value

Answer (score 1):

```
"...value='" + String.fromCharCode(a +64) + "'..."
```

You are missing the single quotes.